# Using FB login can not get loginUrl

Tags: facebook-login

I download php-sdk from  https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk,
and I made reference to example.php and copy codes to my php script.

```
require_once("class/facebook.php");

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId'  => '505646406XXXXX',
'secret' => '4e9b16ac2d072c03426fcdXXXXXXX',
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user) {
try {
// Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
error_log($e);
$user = null;
}
}

if ($user) {
$logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
}
echo $loginUrl;
```

But $loginUrl is empty.
Why? can someone helpme?
Thanks!!

Comment: Just call the method without making it depend on the `$user` variable - what do you get then?

Comment: I want get $loginUrl to add to my html page. use my img.
like: <a href="#" onclick='window.top.location.href="$loginUrl";'><img src="images/member-FB-login-btn.jpg" width="118" height="22" border="0" /></a>
What I need to modify anything?

Comment: First of all that does not answer my question, and second of all, why would you use onclick instead of just putting the URL into the `href` attribute of the link ...?

Comment: Because before I'm reference someone offers method on the network before. window.top.location.href="http://www.facebook.com/connect/uiserver.php?app_id="+encodeURIComponent("app id")+"&next="+encodeURIComponent("http://www.xxxx.com.tw/fblogin.aspx?BackURL=http://www.xxxx.com.tw/default.aspx")+"&display=popup&perms=email,user_birthday&fbconnect=1&method=permissions.request";
 But it seems not, so I refer emample.php.

Comment: Please don't post extended codes in comments, they are hard to read there. Edit your question instead if you have something really relevant to add. Besides that, I can barely understand what you are trying to say. And you still have not answered my question. Last chance, before I'm out.

Comment: Sorry, because I am Chinese, English is not my mother language, so I really don't understand your mean at first answer. I do not know how to login with FB account, I just refer method on the network.

Comment: I meant that you should just see what the method getLoginUrl returns, without putting it into `if($user)`. And if you have no idea how facebook login works, then please go read the official docs.